# HTML injected with .load() don't execute jquery functions

Tags: jquery

I used .load() function to cut my pages in different parts, like header, menu, footer ...

But I realize that HTML injected with .load() isn't compatible with my jquery functions.

There is a great exemple :

I have a header.html that I load on my main page :

```
 <div class="row justify-content-end">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <nav class="header">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" target=_blank>Télécharger mon CV</a></li>
                <li>hello@floran.me</li>
                <li><a href="#menu" class="openMenu"><i class="icon icon-sort-bold icon-32"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

On my script.js, I call a page named menu.html by clicking on the burger menu, and that was working before I decided to cut the header into a different page.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var DemiWindow = windowWidth / 2;
    
    // Appels includes
    $('#main-menu').load("includes/menu.html");
    $('.sticky-top').load("includes/header.html");
    
    function openMenu(){
        $('#main-menu').animate({left: 0}, 500, function(){});
        $('.main-content').animate({marginLeft: -DemiWindow}, 1000, function(){
            $('.main-content').css('margin-left', 'auto');
            $(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
                if (event.key == "Escape") {
                $('#main-menu').animate({left: windowWidth}, 500, function(){});
                }
            });
        });
    }
    function closeMenu(){
        $('#main-menu').animate({left: windowWidth}, 500, function(){});
        console.log(windowWidth);
    }
    
    $('#main-menu').css('left', windowWidth);
    
    $(window).resize(function() {
        windowWidth = $(window).width();
        DemiWindow = windowWidth / 2;
        $('#main-menu').css('left', windowWidth);
    });
    
    $('.openMenu').click(openMenu);
    
    $('.closeMenu').click(closeMenu);
    
    
});
```

I didn't read something about using jquery functions on injected HTML code, do you have a tip to keep it working ?

Thank you!

Comment: It seems like you either need to use callbacks from the async `load()` calls, or delegated event handlers, or possibly both. It's not clear what the exact issue is from your description of the issue or the code provided

Comment: There shouldn't be a "late-load" issue *with the code provided*.   You don't appear to call `openMenu()` (in the provided code).   You haven't included `.main-content` (in the provided code).  If `.main-content` is late-loaded (loaded after openMenu() called) then it would have the animate/css applied.  You could load the "framework" of the menu (main-menu/main-content) in the main page then the content *inside* that.

Comment: *something about using jquery on injected HTML code* - this is only for *event binding*.   Jquery only works on what's there at the time it runs, so if you add some html after your code has run, it won't be affected by it.   So for `$("#newitem").click(...` if newitem isn't there, it doesn't get the event.  This is where event delegation comes in, see here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @freedomn-m I understand what you mean, but in my case, the click action that open the menu is written after the .load(), so it should work, right ?

Comment: Hence my first comment "There shouldn't be a "late-load" issue with the code *provided*.".   I was addressing your fears regarding "injected HTML code".

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your explanation. I putted the entire jquery code on the topic if you want to take a look. Right now, I have the burger icon to trigger on the index.html, and the `#main-menu` too, then, the content is inside the menu.html. In the script file, I first load the menu.html with `load()`, then defining what is the `openmenu()` function, then condition triggering it with `click()` at the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

So just found the problem by reading comments and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) topic.

So, functions like `.click` aren't working for elements which were not into the DOM on document loading, even if the function is placed after their load on the js code. So I had to replace :

```
$('.openMenu').click(openMenu);
$('.closeMenu').click(closeMenu);
```

by

```
$(document).on('click', '.openMenu', openMenu);
$(document).on('click', '.closeMenu', closeMenu);
```

and this code is now working for every dynamic element added after DOM loading.